# restore sharepoint list lookup value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, lookup-column, sharepoint-list, spfieldlookupvalue

I have simple Sharepoint list named Alist with lookup value column.

the lookup value column returns fields from other list named Blist. accidentally I have deleted this Blist and in Alist all lookup value disappeared, after I restored Blist but in Alist lookup values didn't restored.

is there some way to restore lookup values in Alist?

Comment: Have you enabled versioning in Alist? Have you any backups?

Comment: no, version is not enabled and what type of backup do you mean?

Comment: Backup with DPM or some backing up program? The information is saved in List[ID] and because you haven't set that this is cascade lookup and you cannot delete this, so when you delete listB the values dissapear.
> so you need backup of SharePoint for restore this values, otherwise you must set this manually again.

Comment: It's separate program. You have your own SharePoint or in some company? Ask infrastructure of application manager..

Comment: I backup my sharepoint Blist but in A list there is no any lookup value. if I edit lookup column there is written "Get information from:" and no more information

Comment: I mean backups from past not from now.... If you havent backups, you must fill this column manually again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListB has now different GUID than the original one. GUID is used at ListA for referencing (original) ListB. You need to change referencing ListB GUID from ListA - this can be done but is a bit hard to do.

- First, check out new ListB GUID [Reference](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/finding-the-id-guid-for-a-sharepoint-list/).
- Save ListA as template (with content), save it on disk (stp packet)
- rename `*.stp` to `*.zip` & unpack it.
- from `manifest.xml` find the original referenced column and it's list GUID, change it to new ListB GUID
- zip `manifest.xml` and rename `*.zip` to `*.stp`
- upload file to list templates.
- Create new list (new 'ListA') from this template -> reference should work now.

Have done this couple of times and it works.

Comment: It seems good way, now I got manifest.xml file so how can I find original referenced column and it's list GUID?

Comment: it is very good way but instance of .zip I have to do it with .cab, thank you

Comment: the `stp` file needs to be packaged using the command `makecab.exe manifest.xml mytemplatename.stp` 
 https://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/manually-edit-a-stp-manifest-template-file-for-sharepoint/