# SharePoint list template doesn't appear in Add apps

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list, guid

I have a SharePoint list, I saved its template, downloaded it and renamed the .stp extension to .zip.

After that, I extracted manifest.xml file, edited it and changed the list's GUID.

After that, I added the manifest.xml file to the archive, renamed it to .stp and uploaded it to the SharePoint site.

But when I am trying to add this list, it doesn't appear in Add apps.

Here is an image of how it is displayed in List Template Gallery:

[image]

Comment: Which version of sharepoint you are on? And what as the need to edit manifest.xml?

Comment: sharepoint 2013, here is explained why I need change GUID id https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255365/restore-sharepoint-list-lookup-value/255538#255538

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SharePoint Template files (.stp) are **not** zip files. They are actually cabinet files - so the correct extension if you want to browse their content would be .cab, not .zip. Since you were able to rename the template file to .zip and extract its content, I assume you aren't using the default Windows archive manager but instead you are using some external tool - probably 7zip based on its diffusion (and the fact it is free).

So, back to your issue - based on the small screenshot you posted I think that whatever edited file you uploaded to SharePoint wasn't a valid cabinet file (some of the list column are empty, probably an indication that SharePoint wasn't able to parse the template correctly).

Anyway, without more detail it would be difficult to pinpoint the exact nature of the error (did you rename the manifest.xml file to manifest.stp and tried to upload that? Did you create a new zip archive with the manifest and renamed it to .stp??) so I will suggest you follow this procedure instead:

1. take the **original** .stp file you downloaded from SharePoint, rename it to [filename].**cab**.
2. the file icon should have changed to the icon of a Windows cabinet archive, now doubleclick it and it should open like a normal folder/archive directly into Windows Explorer.
3. Extract the contained manifest.xml file by dragging it to a location of your choice (alternatively, you should also be able to doubleclick the file and Windows should show you and "extract file to folder" prompt).
4. edit the manifest file to fit your need. Based on your other question, you will have to find the lookup field you need to fix and change its source list identifier to point to the new GUID of the lookup list that you have recreated. Please, try to be sure you change the CORRECT id. If you are not sure, maybe ask a different question and ask for further assistance.
5. now that you have the new, edited manifest.xml file it is time to wrap it into a cab archive.
6. open a command prompt window and navigate to the folder that contains your new edited manifest file.
7. now, enter the command:

   `makecab.exe manifest.xml newFixedTemplate.stp`
8. after the command completes, you should have a file named newFixedTemplate.stp in the same folder - upload that file to the SharePoint template gallery.

Comment: thank you, but in .cab file I also got .000 file (60000000.000) so how can I handle this?

Comment: @VasoMiruashvili have you tried opening the file? What does it contain? I think that could be the list data if you checked the "include data" option when originally creating the template on SharePoint, but I can't be sure without knowing the file contents.

Comment: I have done it with makecab.exe and .ddf file, I make cab file with my manifest.xml and 60000000.000 file. thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Do not extract the contents, directly open the zip and edit the file and save.

Comment: I tried but windows can not open this zip. it says that zip is invalid