# Sharepoint's saved list template doesnt loads all item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, splistitem, sharepoint-list

I have SharePoint 2013 list with 13897 items in it, I saved it as a template with include contents.

[image]

Now I am trying to create a new list but it doesn't load all items.

[image]

and if I open this newly created list, there is an error something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because there are lots of files and probably the template file is really large, the creation from this template probably timed out and won't be created properly.

I recommend to use Export-SPWeb and ImportSPWeb, where you can simply export and import whole library

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/export-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/import-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps

or
http://prabathf.blogspot.com/2012/02/export-and-import-sharepoint-list.html

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity <SiteURL> -Path <FileName.cmp> -ItemUrl <URLList> -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions

Import-SPweb -Identity <SiteUrl> -Path <FileName.cmp>
```

Comment: Agreed.  There are most likely too many items for the template to finish.  Powershell is oging to be your best bet if you need all of the content as well

Comment: thank you, but what is .cmp file? I got .stp file of list

Comment: this is the same like .bak, its the file which is used for backing and restoring with SharePoint

Comment: So I only need Import-SPweb for my case, right?

Comment: No you need both, Export this List with first where ItemUrl is /lists/ListName and after this Import this web to web you want it

Comment: can I edit cmp file? I need to edit it and change giudID.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255365/restore-sharepoint-list-lookup-value

Comment: Why you need to change guid? I think there will be new guids for everything.